# Object.assign overrides original refereneces?

Tags: javascript

I tried to "merge" two objects with [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), but somehow the original objects are overriden. See the example:

```js
var x = {x:1};
var y = {y:2};

var z = Object.assign(x, y);

// what I've expected
console.log(z); // {"x": 1, "y": 2}

// what I haven't expected
console.log(x); // {"x": 1, "y": 2}
```

Comment: That's because you didn't provide a new object to merge into `Object.assign({}, x, y);.` Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Aww man, how could I overlook this... thanks guys :)

Comment: First thing should be to go to the docs then one should get here. _of course if docs doesn't make sense_ ;)

Comment: @Jai as you see in my question, I was there before :) But it seems I was a bit too fast...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty object must be provided as the first argument of `Object.assign` for a new merged object to be created.

```js
var x = {
  x: 1
};
var y = {
  y: 2
};

var z = Object.assign({}, x, y);

// new object
console.log(z); // {"x": 1, "y": 2}

// still the same
console.log(x); // {"x": 1}
console.log(y); // {"y": 2}
```

[You can read more information about `Object.assign` here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change like below

```
var z = Object.assign({},x, y);
```

Here is the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ht7jumh6/

Answer (score 1):

Pass an empty `{}` to `assign()` as the first parameter.

```js
var x = {x:1};
var y = {y:2};

var z = Object.assign({},x, y);

console.log(z); // {"x": 1, "y": 2}

console.log(x); // {"x": 1}
```